# Arguments of an imported function - so a callback - req.body.value is not defined

Tags: node.js, api, http, post, request

I'm working currently on the Google API. I try to upload a file to some folders on the cloud.

When I try to pass the values of req.body as callback arguments,  my console returns me that req is NOT defined.

However, just before to call the function, I make a test to appreciate the values of my variables and the test return me some values.

Here my router.js :

```
router.post("/files", function(req, res){
        console.log("request reached !");
        console.log("req.body.word :" + req.body.word); // "some word"
            console.log("req.body.url :" + req.body.url);// "some url"
            // I catch theses value in some variable
            var word = req.body.word; 
            var url = req.body.url;
        DriveAPI.insertDrive(word, url);  // Now my console return me that
                                          // req is **Not** defined
});
```

Here my quickstart.js :

```
module.exports.insertDrive = function  (word, url) { // again, req is Not defined

  folderId = 'some id';
var fileMetadata = {
  'name': req.body.word ,
  parents: [folderId]
};
var media = {
  mimeType: 'image/jpg',
  body: fs.createReadStream(req.body.url)
};
drive.files.create({
  resource: fileMetadata,
  media: media,
  fields: 'id'
}, function (err, file) {
  if (err) {
    // Handle error
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log('File Id: ', file.id);
  }

  console.log("insert Drive finished =) !")
});
}
```

How pass the value of my req.body as arguments of my callback? 
Thanks

Comment: You're not passing `req` to `insertDrive`, so `req` is not defined in `insertDrive` scope. I'd pass it along: `DriveAPI.insertDrive(req)` and get it: `module.exports.insertDrive = function(req)`. It should work right away, since you're not using the previously passed arguments anyway.